# Using single sign into multi domain websites

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, kerberos, openldap

I am very new to this SSO, Kerberos. My aim is to use a single user account to allow the employees to login into various domains(like Github, Gmail, AWS internal wiki's..) and access control over each employee group. I have explored on LDAP, SSO, Kerberos but couldn't understand how to achieve them. Can anyone give a detailed explanation on how to achieve this

Comment: Kerberos is not meant to be used on the internet, it is meant to be used in local corporate networks. You should probably look into SAML. Overall this is pretty complicated topic and your question is a bit too broad.

Comment: Are there any existing well-known services which satisfy the above requirements

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment Kerberos is not meant to be used on the internet, it is meant to be used in local corporate networks. SAML works good for this case

Existing services I have explored are OneLogin, Centrify but mojor disadvantage with this is many well developed services like bitbucket or github don't support SAML based authentication. SAML configuration for web based systems is easy and readily available but for native applications again one has to do it on their own.